# MySQL access denied 1045 error

Tags: mysql, networking, mysql-error-1045

I'm getting a very strange error, I've created a user 'testuser' with the following credentials:

```
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I have also modified my /etc/mysql/my.cnf not to bind to any single address. (Which afaik should accept connections from anywhere?) And restarted mysql.

And I can connect locally no problem.

I am running inside a virtual box on ubunutu.

Trying to connect from my windows machine, gives me MySQL error number 1045 Access denied for user 'testuser'@'192.168.0.22'.

I'm confident that it's not a networking problem as changing the host or port gives a different error "Cannot connect to the specified instance"

Logging in as root and looking at the users table - all looks as expected. (Single row, '%' for host and all permissions set.)

I've been banging my head against the wall all afternoon... can anyone suggest any other possible causes for this error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Could not connect to the specified instance.

MySQL Error Number 1045
Access denied for user 'testuser'@'192.168.0.22' (using password: YES)

If you want to check the network connection, please click the Ping button."

(Clicking the ping button gives:

"Pinging vbox
Reply from 192.168.0.11: Time = 1ms TTL = 64
Reply from 192.168.0.11: Time = 0ms TTL = 64
...")

Comment: Check the password. Is it correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run the `GRANT` statement with the `IDENTIFIED BY`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure why this is necessary, as the documentation implies that setting the pw in `CREATE USER` applies globally, but in my experience it is necessary to specify it in the `GRANT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html